# Image is not fitting correctly in div

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

Image is not getting fully responsive with`img-responsive` class in Bootstrap.

Below is the `css` code used.

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

Comment: try giving that img tag width: 100%

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your `custom.css`-- you have only `max-width: 100%;`, add this one to your banner `width: 100%;`

```
img {
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%; <-- added
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add following css

```
.banner_image_Div img {    
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Apply this css on your IMG

```
.banner_image_Div img {
    display: block;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try adding this to your css:

```
.banner_image_Div img { width: 100%; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try in css property of image balise to set :

```
width: 100%;
```

Without your css, it's a bit hard to find why.

Answer (score 0):

Try to edit your image. increase some some size of it and then give it 100% width when placing inside banner_image_Div. your problem will be solved. this time your image has maximum size that is not more than your div size .